# Jupyter lab autocomplete does not show hint types

Tags: autocomplete, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Recently my Jupyter lab broke down, so I have reinstalled it. Since adding `Compiler.use_jedi = False` it has stopped show hint types. It just writes `<unknown>` opposite the hint

[the screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/DJwqWWn)

I have installed hinterland extension too